# How "deep" should question tags go?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

Re: [Scope of do-while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8068814/438992)

It had been tagged with "do-while", "loops", "declaration". It's a question regarding Java scoping rules, but the three tags I removed seemed excessive, and too generic to be of any real value.

Then I thought to myself "do the tags cause harm?" and "so what?"

How specific should tags be in a case like this? I think it's simple scoping, and tags like "do-while" should be reserved for language-neutral questions like "Why use a do-while instead of xxx" or something, but now I'm not so sure.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I think at least [do-while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do-while) was appropriate on that question. The underlying problem might be caused by scoping, but the question was specifically about a do-while loop in Java. That's how the OP discovered the issue, and it's reasonable to assume other people will too.

I don't know how many people search the [do-while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do-while) tag by itself for questions to answer, but I'm sure they're used to filtering out any languages that they don't know, or otherwise don't feel comfortable answering questions in. I don't think that tag needs to be reserved for language-agnostic questions.